# how to configure react-helmet and change html lang attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I can see a list of examples of how to use react-helmet to change

```
<html lang='en|es|ti|'>
```

Below I have public/index.html and please suggest me step-by-step procedure to adopt react-helmet. Since index.html is a static html, outside of react root and so I am kind of misaligned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charSet='utf-8'></meta>
  <meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='ie=edge'></meta>
  <meta name='format-detection' content='telephone=no'></meta>
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change

```
<html lang="es">
```

dynamically, will my page translated to spanish ? Is there a proper way to do ?

Comment: Where is your React code? Have you followed the instructions in the react-helmet [README](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#readme)? Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: it's absolutely normal to have it outside of react root. Otherwise you could just use plain React to change the attributes. `react-helmet` works directly on DOM.

Comment: Got it. I can see a changes. I have another question. If Someone change the language, I am changing html lang='lang' property. But the page is not translated to the selected one. am i missing anything ?

Comment: @kulls lang attribute does not translate the page. It is used so that search engines and crawlers can identify the language in which the page is written. see https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2016/06/using-the-html-lang-attribute/